# What is the aesthetic style of Journey called?

Tags: style-identification, style

So many artists and games right now are making art in [this sort of style](https://www.google.com/search?q=journey+screenshots&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=989&tbm=isch&imgil=VMj0kPz5kJfNNM%253A%253BxqhgsHU1osxw4M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fthatgamecompany.com%25252Fgames%25252Fjourney%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=VMj0kPz5kJfNNM%253A%252CxqhgsHU1osxw4M%252C_&usg=__WG7EjWQwnqAtxTjbYrNHm1ZwJJU%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiRhZqPisfLAhUL32MKHeheC1AQyjcILw&ei=xEzqVpGTM4u-jwPova2ABQ#imgrc=VMj0kPz5kJfNNM%3A), to me exemplified by the game Journey.

[image]

Or No Man's Sky.

[image]

Another great example is [this deviantart post](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Autumn-564452199)

[image]

I can't find out if this style has a *name*. I want to be able to talk about it in the abstract sense, but I can't discover if people have even given it a name.

From my limited understanding, this aesthetic employs these attributes that I know have names:

- Flat, matte, or soft textures. It's almost like the objects have been cut out of a heavy paper. (Flat Design)
- Very simple or highly geometric composition. (Minimalism)

And then these that I'm not sure have names:

- A simple, desaturated, color palette.
- Extensive use of [bloom shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)).

Is there a name for all of those things combined? Or do I have to simply discuss this by listing these attributes?

Also, do those last two attributes have names as well? The desaturated colors I've simply been referring to as the "hipster color scheme."

Comment: As you comment in your list of characteristics, I think there are many styles mixed into the game. If you're interested in any one of these, you'll have to pull examples from another work I believe

Comment: Though this probably doesn't help you much, there is a similar trend in movies often referred to as "orange and blue" or "orange and teal": http://priceonomics.com/why-every-movie-looks-sort-of-orange-and-blue/

Comment: Even the game Firewatch fits your description---it is similar to [Low-poly art](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/222154194099683483/).